# Slave Select on Analog pin for Can Bus

Tags: can-bus

I have recently made a shield for an arduino mega2560 with among others sensors, a CAN interface (MCP2515 and ISO1050).

The purpose is to create a CAN network with several arduino uno and one Mega. 
Until now, the network is working well on all the Uno but unfortunately not on the Mega. As I have others sensors on the SPI bus, I've kept the MOSI, MISO and SCK pins unchanged (51,50,52) and I put the SS on the Analog pin A13 (number 67 for digital), which was the nearest unused pin I had during the routing process. Before making the shield I was careful and I've check if I could use it as a SS for my purpose.

Despite my caution, it appears that I'm not able to communicate within the CAN bus.

Before going futher, I'm using the SeeedStudio library made for their shield to test the connection. 
I've tried to use A13 (using an #define)and 67 for the

```
SPI_CS_PIN = 67;
```

without any success.

I've also tried to force the bus to be active with a digitalWrite at the beginning of the setup().

```
// demo: CAN-BUS Shield, send data
// loovee@seeed.cc

#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// the cs pin of the version after v1.1 is default to D9
// v0.9b and v1.0 is default D10
const int SPI_CS_PIN = 67;

MCP_CAN CAN(SPI_CS_PIN);                                    // Set CS pin

void setup()
{
     Serial.begin(115200);

while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_500KBPS))              // init can bus : baudrate = 500k
{
    Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield init fail");
    Serial.println(" Init CAN BUS Shield again");
    delay(100);
}
Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield init ok!");
}

unsigned char stmp[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void loop()
{
// send data:  id = 0x00, standrad frame, data len = 8, stmp: data buf
stmp[7] = stmp[7]+1;
if(stmp[7] == 100)
{
    stmp[7] = 0;
    stmp[6] = stmp[6] + 1;

    if(stmp[6] == 100)
    {
        stmp[6] = 0;
        stmp[5] = stmp[6] + 1;
    }
}

CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x00, 0, 8, stmp);
delay(100);                       // send data per 100ms
}
```

If you have any idea on why it's not working and a way to solve this problem, please let me know :)

Undeadguy.

Comment: Try adding `pinMode(53, OUTPUT);` to the start of your `setup()`.

Comment: I've tried : no success :(

However could you explain to me what effect making this pin as an output could have on the other pin ? Is this particular pin always selected as the SS ?

Comment: That is the hardware SS pin. The ATMega's SPI peripheral uses the direction of that pin to determine the direction of the SPI port. It has to always be OUTPUT for the SPI to work as a master.